# Is it dangerous to move a variable from .bss to .data?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have some global buffers that GCC wants to place into bss. Unfortunately this would result in the bss section exceeding its allocated size. I'd rather not change the linker file for this mess of a project (there are many reasons, just humour me here).

Is it dangerous to move a variable from .bss to .data?

I did it like this:

```
uint8_t data_queue[256] __attribute__ ((section(".data_queues")));
```

Then in the linker file I added `.data_queues` to the `.data` section. I checked the map file and the buffer is indeed in the `.data` section.

I memset `data_queue` to 0 at the start of my program.

Am I likely to run into issues if I do this? Is it a terrible idea? Is there a better solution?

Comment: The problem that the `memset` might get optimzed away if the compiler believes this data is zero anyway. The setting to zero should be done in the startup code (before `main`).

Comment: @EugeneSh., ok, that's good to know (makes sense too). I don't really rely on the elements being zero I think, so it's probably not a big deal regardless.

Comment: The problem is that it's the compiler who is relying on it :) Like if you have some code explicitly setting some elements to zero, the compiler might decide to optimize these assignments away. But sure, you might get away without ever seeing any problem.

Comment: just keep in mind your binary will increase in size in about 256 bytes

Comment: @EugeneSh., ah, ok. Unfortunately I don't have access to the startup code. I am working on a library that is linked to a bunch of other libraries, one of which is containing the startup code. If I disable the optimizations, will that keep compiler from doing clever things?

Comment: @user2162550, yeah that's ok in this case.

Comment: @user2162550 Why would it? The data is still considered by the compiler to be zero-initialized.

Comment: @Eugene Sh if it goes into `.data` section this means it occupying space in binary (something like `PT_LOAD` attribute or similar in `elf`, I don't remember) and its content is copied from binary to memory, unlike `.bss` which is just populated with zeros in startup. disagree? final binary is represented by the final output sections (or segments) which place it in the `.data` section

Comment: It goes to the `.data_queues` section, and depending on whether it is supposed to contain initialized or uninitialized data it may or may not consume the binary size.

Comment: @EugeneSh. OP says `Then in the linker file I added .data_queues to the .data section. I checked the map file and the buffer is indeed in the .data section.`

Comment: @user2162550 Ah, OK, so the OP have explicitly increased the `.data` size. Missed this point

Comment: @EugeneSh., yeah, .data is a large section so I had room to grow it.

Comment: Well. Since you are not relying on the initial value of the array, you can simply give it some non-zero initializer, and it will go to the `.data` automatically.

Comment: Or... It appears that there is a GCC option to tell it not to use BSS! `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: @EugeneSh., thanks, that moved a bunch of stuff to .data, so I'll have to double check that it didn't break something else. Looks like I have a few suggestions to try.

Comment: @Catsunami If you used the compiler option, that should not break anything as these will still be initialized to zeros, but in `.data` section (I.e. the zeros will eat up you binary size).

Comment: @EugeneSh., you should post that as an answer, I actually ended up using your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own section. Do not "move" it do the .data segment as it is an UB (you don have corresponding data in the .rodata segment).

Just add to your linker script :

```
  .mysection : 
  {
    KEEP(*(.mysection))           
    KEEP(*(.mysection*))         

  } >RAM
```

---

```
uint8_t data_queue[256] __attribute__ ((section(".mysection"), used));
```

Comment: where does the standard says it's an UB? also, why using `KEEP`? why disable optimization of non referenced data?

Comment: And what permissions this section has?

Comment: It will keep the data even if there is no reference in the program. (At least I understand that is something OP needs). If not of course the KEEP can be removed

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN same as `RAM` memory area

Comment: Ok I will do this instead, that is probably a better idea. And sorry, what is `UB`?

Comment: Undefined Behavior